# In node.js, the console displays the success log, but localhost: 3000 is not connected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a simple web application using node.js, express and mysql.

When I connect to get /employees, I try to console.log the data of the linked DB. However, when connected to localhost, an infinite delay occurs.

What's wrong with me?

**index.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json)

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'ps',
    database: 'EmployeeDB'
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
    if(!err)
    console.log('DB connection succeded');
    else
    console.log('DB connection failed \n Error : '+ JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Express server is running at port no:3000'));

app.get('/employees',(res, req)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Employee',(err, rows, fields)=>{
        if(!err)
        console.log(rows);
        // console.log(rows[0].EmpID);
        else
        console.log(err);
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you also show the error from console?

Comment: Only "Express server is running at port no: 3000
DB connection succeded "is output and the connection is not available to localhost.

Comment: The `console` doesn't provide any information to the client; those messages will remain server-side for your own use. To reach the client, you'll have to send data through the [`Response`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res). That can be done with Express' convenience methods such as [`response.send()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) and [`response.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json), or with [`response.write()` and `response.end()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) from Node's own API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something, like the data:

```
app.get('/employees',(req, res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Employee',(err, rows, fields)=>{
        if(!err)
            res.json(rows);
        else
            res.status(500).send('Error found');
    })
});
```

Also, parameters are reversed from normal – `(res, req)` vs. `(req, res)` as @JonathanLonowski catch it.

Comment: Note that the parameters are reversed – `(res, req)` rather than `(req, res)` for `res.json()` and similar to work.

Comment: I tried the answer but it is still the same situation.

Comment: Good catch @JonathanLonowski!

Comment: Did you try it after put on the right place the `req` and `res` paramenters @yori?

Comment: It's still the same.
And the question is, is not the order of the parameters res, req correct?

Comment: @yori Generally, no. You can technically name the parameters with any identifiers, but Express will pass in arguments in the order of `(Request, Response)`, with `(req, res)` being a typical abbreviation for them. Regardless, methods like `.json()`, `.status()`, and `.send()` should be available on the 2nd parameter.